# BASH Bulk rename movie files using EXIFTOOL as DATETIME format recursively [Year-Month-Day][DayofWeek] [Hours.Minutes.Seconds].extention

Tags: bash, datetime, rename, mov, exiftool

I want to organize my whole family photos and movies. I have a sample code, but i cannot exchange characters in filename using -tr or -sed commands in BASH code and EXIFTOOL by Phil Harvey. Any one has an idea?

```
#!/bin/bash
# scan the files you need

for i in *jpg *mov *jpeg *mpg; *avi *mp4 do

# Get the extension of the file

extension=${i##*.}

# Extract metadata from the file

datetime=$( exiftool -f -s3 -"DateTimeOriginal" "${i}" )

# If the datetime value is empty (returned '-' because of the '-f' option)
# then read another tag

if [ "${datetime}" = '-' ]; then
    datetime=$( exiftool -f -s3 -"MediaCreateDate" "${i}")
fi

# Construct the new filename from the metadata gathered above

newfilename="${datetime}.${extension}"


# Check if the destination filename already exists, and if not,
# create the file

if [ ! -e "${newfilename}" ]; then

 echo mv -v "${i}" "${newfilename}"

else
    echo "${i} would get renamed to ${newfilename} but that file already exists."
fi

done
```

Comment: are you asking how to use `tr` and `sed` to modify `$newfilename`? ps change `for i in *jpg *mov *jpeg *mpg; *avi *mp4 do` to `for i in *jpg *mov *jpeg *mpg *avi *mp4; do`

Answer (score 4):

A script isn't necessary for this, Exiftool can do it by itself.

Your command would look something like this:
`exiftool -ext jpg -ext mov -ext jpeg -ext mpg -ext avi -ext mp4 -d '[%Y-%m-%d][%A] [%H.%M.%S].%%e' '-Filename<MediaCreateDate' '-Filename<DateTimeOriginal' FileOrDir`

The [`-ext` (`-extension`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ext-EXT---ext-EXT--extension) limits what file extension to operate on.
The [`-d` (`-dateFormat`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#d-FMT--dateFormat) and the format string that follows it tells Exiftool what format to use for date/time type tags.  More info found under [Common Date Format Codes](https://exiftool.org/filename.html#codes).

The next two options tell exiftool that the file will be renamed according to the specified tags (`MediaCreateDate` or `DateTimeOriginal`).  Earlier assignments to the same tag, in this case `Filename`, are overridden by later assignments, so `DateTimeOriginal` will be used if it exists, otherwise `MediaCreateDate`.  If neither item exists, a minor error will occur and the file will not be renamed.  Same thing will happen if a file with that name already exists, but `%%c` can be added to the date format string to add an incremental number to the filename.

One thing to take note of is that the `MediaCreateDate` in video files is supposed to be set to UTC and programs that read it are supposed to adjust the timestamp to the local time. See fourth paragraph on the [Quicktime tags page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html). But not all cameras, usually older ones, will set it properly, . Exiftool will return the timestamp as is, which may not be correct.  If you want exiftool to adjust it to the local time, then you can add the [`-api QuickTimeUTC` option](https://exiftool.org/ExifTool.html#QuickTimeUTC).

Here's some sample output where I used `testname` instead of `filename`.

```
'X:/!temp/0615090217.jpg' --> 'X:/!temp/[2009-06-15][Monday] [02.17.00].jpg'
'X:/!temp/2013-07-18_12.19.38 - Copy.Jpg' --> 'X:/!temp/[2013-07-18][Thursday] [12.19.38].Jpg'
'X:/!temp/DSC_7689 after.JPG' --> 'X:/!temp/[2006-08-19][Saturday] [09.13.28].JPG'
'X:/!temp/FujiFilmFinePixF200EXR_F0Standard (Provia).jpg' --> 'X:/!temp/[2009-01-25][Sunday] [14.10.46].jpg'
'X:/!temp/FujiFilmFinePixS5Pro.jpg' --> 'X:/!temp/[2006-12-20][Wednesday] [07.20.58].jpg'
'X:/!temp/IMGP0713-XL.jpg' --> 'X:/!temp/[2011-03-10][Thursday] [14.10.54].jpg'
'X:/!temp/IMGP0852.jpg' --> 'X:/!temp/[2003-04-20][Sunday] [16.36.53].jpg'
'X:/!temp/IMG_0938.JPG' --> 'X:/!temp/[2000-01-02][Sunday] [03.04.10].JPG'
'X:/!temp/RCNX0001.JPG' --> 'X:/!temp/[2015-12-20][Sunday] [09.09.05].JPG'
'X:/!temp/Test1.mp4' --> 'X:/!temp/[2015-12-25][Friday] [15.46.15].mp4'
'X:/!temp/Test4.jpg' --> 'X:/!temp/[2010-07-05][Monday] [12.53.36].jpg'
'X:/!temp/Test4.mp4' --> 'X:/!temp/[2014-11-11][Tuesday] [11.11.11].mp4'
'X:/!temp/tif.jpg' --> 'X:/!temp/[2003-03-03][Monday] [03.03.03].jpg'
'X:/!temp/xyzzy.jpg' --> 'X:/!temp/[2012-04-04][Wednesday] [04.04.04].jpg'
```

This assumes using bash under Linux/Mac.  On Windows CMD, the single quotes would be changed into double quotes.  Add the [`-r` (`-recurse`) option](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.